# Why can't I set an item in the HttpContext in a module then get it back in my handler?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, httpmodule

In an HttpModule, I put an Item in the Context, like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("MyKey", "Hello world!");
```

Directly under this code (still inside the module), I can retrieve this string from the collection, so I know it got added.

Fast forward to my actual handler (a Web form -- .aspx). I try to get this item back:

```
string myString = HttpContext.Current.Items["MyKey"].ToString();
```

Sadly, it's NULL -- the item is not there.

I spun the collection, and by the time it gets to my handler, the Items collection has two keys:

- AspSession
- AspSessionIDManagerInitializeRequestCalled

After I set the Item in the module, I call RewritePath.  Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that a redirect snuck in there.  So the request where I set the values and the request where I read the values were actually *two separate requests*.  It went so fast that I didn't notice, even when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear about the flow of your code but try using HttpContext.Items instead of HttpContext.Current.Items collection. Check out this link - http://odetocode.com/articles/111.aspx